# Getting the ID of current script programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that is using ajax to consume an api. My current script looks for a script tag with an id of "test-api" and passes the data attribute (an id) to the ajax call to complete the url for lookup.

```
<script src="./bundle/src/js/api.js" id="test-api" data-client="2"></script>
```

Inside my script:

```
var clientId = $('#test-api').data('client');
//short hand 
axios.get('http://url_to_api.com/clients' + clientID)
.then()
```

All of this works quite well, but I have now run into an issue. This script might be duplicated on the same page (as I might need to pull in other "clients") so I need to have ids for all of the scripts.

```
<script src="./bundle/src/js/api.js" id="test-api" data-client="2"></script>
<script src="./bundle/src/js/api.js" id="test-two-api" data-client="5"></script>
<script src="./bundle/src/js/api.js" id="test-three-api" data-client="6"></script>
```

I tried using

```
var script = document.currentScript;
script = script[script.length - 1]
```

but I keep getting null returned (also regarding this, my script is being placed via a gtm, so it is not always the last script). As I understand, it is null due to this being placed in an .then() function (running after another script finishes).

I guess my question is it possible to actually get the id of the current script without really know what ID is present (not hardcoded into the script)? Unfortunately, I do need to support IE as well so I assume .currentScript is out of the question as well

Comment: Are you trying to get the ID from inside `api.js` or from some other script?

Comment: "*This script might be duplicated on the same page*" - bad idea. Don't load (or assuming it's cached, at least don't parse and execute) the same script multiple times. It seems like what you are actually looking for would be allowing multiple client ids to be passed at once, e.g. `<script src="./bundle/src/js/api.js" id="test-api" data-client="[2, 5, 6]"></script>`